# How to determine the tangent plane of a vector function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, vectors, vector-analysis

I got a problem that I have to determine the tangent plane, normal line and gradient of a vector function in a specific point.

This problem gives me this vector function $h$:

$h: (0, +\infty) \times (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$

$h(x,y)=(x^y,x^x\sinh(y))$

and the point $(1, 1)$.

I don't even know how to start solving this problem.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense to me. Tangent planes are defined for surfaces, that is, maps from an (open subset of) $\mathbb{R}^2$ to some $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>2$ (in your problem, the tangent plane would just be $\mathbb{R}^2$). Normal lines are defined for hypersurfaces, which is absurd here. And gradients, as I know them, are constructed from numeric functions, not vector functions. I suppose you could take the gradient of each component, to do that, just compute the partial derivatives of those components.

Comment: What is the precise statement of the problem? Seems that they should be asking for the jacobian matrix.

Comment: @Compacto the exact statement of the problem is:
Let $h: (0, +\infty) \times (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the function given by $h(x,y)=(x^y,x^x\sinh(y))$
Determine the tangent plane to the graph of the function, the normal line, and the gradient of the function at the point (1, 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph of the function is the surface with parametrization

$$H: (0,+\infty)^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$$

given by $H(x,y) = (x, y, x^y, x^x\sinh(y))$. The tangent plane at each point of the surface is generated by the partial derivatives of $H$, which are

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = (1, 0, yx^{y-1},x^x(1+\log x)\sinh(y))$

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = (0,1, x^y\log x,x^x\cosh(y))$

At the point $(1,1)$, they are the tangent vectors

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(1,1) = (1,0,1,\sinh(1))$

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}(1,1) = (0,1,0,\cosh(1))$

So, points on the tangent plane at that point are of the form $(1,1) + t(1,0,1,\sinh(1)) + s(0,1,0,\cosh(1))$, for arbitrary $s, t$.

The normal line still makes no sense, because the orthogonal space of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has $2$ dimensions and not one (it would be a "normal plane"). Same thing for the "gradient". You could calculate the gradients of the components, which would be the partial derivatives of each component, and I already got them:

$grad H_1 = (yx^{y-1}, x^y\log x)$

$grad H_2 = (x^x(1+ \log x)\sinh(y), x^x\cosh(y))$